# Push to React Router History from Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to control the router component `<HashRouter></HashRouter>` from my application's root level `<App> </App>`component (which contains the router as a child).

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
       // potentially push to history here
    }
    render () {
        <HashRouter></HashRouter>
    }
}
```

Is this possible? (Using react-router-dom at 4.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Non-route component can use `withRouter` (it's actually a wrapper for `<Route children>`) in order to get access to router-specific props, particularly `history`.

`withRouter` component should reside inside router so it cannot be applied to `App`. *potentially push to history here* task should be delegated to `<Router>` child component enhanced with `withRouter`:

```
@withRouter
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.push(...);
  }
  render () {
    return null;
  }
}
```